# Get value of spinbutton grouped with label (Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I'm designing an interactive schema, with TextBoxes connected with Connectors, and spinbuttons that indicate the "strenght" of the connectors. Right now I only want to get the names and values and connections of elements for future use. My problem is that I have each spinbutton grouped with a label (so that in my future code I'll be able to show the spinbutton value), and in the following code I can't get the value of the spinbutton. I tried all sort of things, like `subshp.OLEFormat.Object.Value` without success.

I'm pasting the full code for context, but my problem resides in code after `For Each subshp In shMyShape.GroupItems`. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CB1_Click()
    Dim shMyShape, subshp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim theSubShapes as String

    Worksheets("MySchema").Range("A1:M100").ClearContents
    i = 1
    For Each shMyShape In Worksheets("MySchema").Shapes

        If (shMyShape.Connector) Then
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 1) = "Shape name: "
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 2) = shMyShape.Name
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 3) = "Connector. Comes from " & shMyShape.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text & " and goes to " & shMyShape.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If (shMyShape.Type = msoTextBox) Then
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 1) = "Shape name: "
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 2) = shMyShape.Name
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 3) = "Textbox, and its value is: " & shMyShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If (shMyShape.Type = msoGroup) Then
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 1) = "Shape name: "
            Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 2) = shMyShape.Name
                theSubShapes = ""

                'here starts my problem
                For Each subshp In shMyShape.GroupItems
                    theSubShapes = theSubShapes & "-" & subshp.Name & "/" 'Here I need to get the spinbutton value (e.g., subshp.Value or subshp.OLEFormat.Object.Value)
                Next subshp
                Worksheets("MySchema").Cells(i, 3) = theSubShapes
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: SOLVED. In case someone gets here, finally the solution was `subshp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value`. Not a logical approach in my case, but just trial and error :(

Answer (score 0):

It is a silly question but have you tried:

```
 subshp.Value 'instead of subshp.Values
```

Comment: Yes, its just a typo in the question. Edited now. Thanks for aswering.